# Opentok output mode both individual and composed?

Tags: video, opentok

I am working on generating archives with Opentok. It allows me to choose the output type.

**Output:individual** allows me to have individual video files in a zip including a json file , which is perfect. But I also need a **composed video** file or in another saying a merged video file composed of each stream in the archive.

Why do I need both of them?

**outputMode: "individual"**

The reason is that I need each video streams in order to have "watson" speech to text running over it . This way, I can generate the speech text in the right order.

**outputMode: "composed"**

I also need a composed video at the end of the recording because I do not want to merge the video after the recording ends.

Can anyone tell me how to succeed it?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have 2 different types of archives for 1 session going at the same time. You might be able to have 2 sessions though and have everyone publish to both of them at the same time and archive them both, one with individual archive and the other as composed.

Comment: I've used individual archiving, but its not audible at all. I understand that we need to do some post processing to make the archives playable. I've used github.com/opentok/archiving-composer and still the video is not audible. Do I need to do any more processing using `ffmpeg`?